# Converting an iterativ function to a recursive one

Tags: java, recursion

Can anybody convert this iterative function to a recursive one? thanks

```
int b = 1; //what should be converted from
for(int i=0;i<=k;i++){
  b=b+1+b;  
}
```

tried this, but got an integer overflow, so I'm obviously doing something wrong

```
public static int o(int k){ //recursive try
  if(k<0) return -1;
  else{
    if(k==0) return 1;
    else return o(k+1+k);  
  }  
}
```

Can anybody convert this iterative function to a recursive one? thanks

Comment: "but got an integer overflow" do you mean a _stack_ overflow? Java doesn't generate errors on integer overflow.

Comment: You get a stack overflow because your termination condition is that `k <= 0`; but (assuming `k` is initially `> 0`), you are making `k` bigger and bigger.

Comment: Are you sure the iterative version is correct? In particular, are you sure that the loop condition `i<=k` is correct? --- Some remarks: we normally surround binary operators with blanks (`i<=k` -> `i <= k`, `o(k+1+k)` -> `o(k + 1 + k)`) --- Even if possible, we should not skip the optional `{` and `}` on one-liner bodies of `if`-, `else`-, `for`-, `wihle`-constructs. --- We should choose meaningful names for methods and parameters: `o` and `k` are very non-descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example showing you the "stack trace" in both the iterative and recursive versions:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 7;

    int b = 1;
    System.out.println("Starting Conditons:");
    System.out.println("b: " + b + ", k: " + k);
    System.out.println("Iterative trace:");
    for(int i=0;i<=k;i++){      
      b=b+1+b;  
      System.out.println("i: " + i + ", b: " + b);
    }
    System.out.println("Iterative: b = " + b);

    b = 1;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Starting Conditons:");
    System.out.println("b: " + b + ", k: " + k);
    System.out.println("Recursive trace:");    
    b = foo(0, k, b);
    System.out.println("Recursive: b = " + b);
  }

  public static int foo(int i, int k, int b) {    
    System.out.println("i: " + i + ", b: " + b);
    if (i > k) {
      return b;
    }
    else {      
      return foo(i+1, k, b+1+b);
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Starting Conditons:
b: 1, k: 7
Iterative trace:
i: 0, b: 3
i: 1, b: 7
i: 2, b: 15
i: 3, b: 31
i: 4, b: 63
i: 5, b: 127
i: 6, b: 255
i: 7, b: 511
Iterative: b = 511

Starting Conditons:
b: 1, k: 7
Recursive trace:
i: 0, b: 1
i: 1, b: 3
i: 2, b: 7
i: 3, b: 15
i: 4, b: 31
i: 5, b: 63
i: 6, b: 127
i: 7, b: 255
i: 8, b: 511
Recursive: b = 511
```